# Javascript - Reselect text after wrap tags around it doesnt work? WYSIWYG

Tags: javascript, html, selection, range

I want to build another WYSIWYG editor. I already have a script to wrap tags around the current selection even for firefox multiple selections but it doesnt reselect the ranges after i edited the html. How can this happen?

This is my code:

```
function wrap(tagName)
{
    var selection;
var elements = [];
var ranges = [];
var rangeCount = 0;
if (window.getSelection)
{
    selection = window.getSelection();
    if (selection.rangeCount)
    {
        rangeCount = selection.rangeCount;
        for (var i=0; i<rangeCount; i++)
        {
            ranges[i] = selection.getRangeAt(i).cloneRange();
            elements[i] = document.createElement(tagName);
            elements[i].appendChild(ranges[i].extractContents());
            ranges[i].insertNode(elements[i]);
            selection.addRange(ranges[i]);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Sorry for my bad English im from Holland.

Comment: You can use `document.execCommand`. It is easy to wrap only tags. [Rich-Text Editing in Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla#Executing_Commands)

Comment: @user1507868 You need to accept Tim's answer, if you had I would have up-voted your question since it was on-topic for me.

Answer (score 2):

Your current code isn't far off, although you will get possibly undesired behaviour for ranges that start in one block element (such as a `<p>` or `<div>`) and end in another. The essential bits you're missing are that you need to set each range to encompass the wrapped content (using `selectNode()`), and that you need to remove all the ranges from the selection and add them back in a separate step.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/dmhPH/1/

Code:

```
function wrap(tagName)
{
    var selection;
    var elements = [];
    var ranges = [];
    var rangeCount = 0;
    var frag;
    var lastChild;
    if (window.getSelection)
    {
        selection = window.getSelection();
        if (selection.rangeCount)
        {
            var i = selection.rangeCount;
            while (i--)
            {
                ranges[i] = selection.getRangeAt(i).cloneRange();
                elements[i] = document.createElement(tagName);
                elements[i].appendChild(ranges[i].extractContents());
                ranges[i].insertNode(elements[i]);
                ranges[i].selectNode(elements[i]);
            }

            // Restore ranges
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            i = ranges.length;
            while (i--)
            {
                selection.addRange(ranges[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much that's what i wanted!

Comment: There's only one thing what i found out is that when you want to create this effect `<u><b>H</b>ello world<b>!</b></u>` the code adds one empty b-element before and one empty b-element after the current selection like this `<b></b><u><b>H</b>ello world<b>!</b></u><b></b>` how can this happen?